# Running Spring Boot with two active profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a bit confused about this as I've never encountered this scenario. I'm sure theres an easy solution. This is what my project structure looks like:

```
.
├── application
|   |── build.gradle
│   └── setting.gradle
|── application-app
|   |── src
|   |── resources
|      └── application-dev.yml
│   └── build.gradle
|── application-core
|   |── src
|   |── resources
|      |── application-core.properties 
|      └── application.properties
|   └── build.gradle
```

The project which I run is `application-app` with the dev profile set active in my IDE run configuration. However, due to changes, I need the properties specified in `application-core.properties` as well, because this subproject contains functionality I need in `application-app`.

The content of `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=core
```

The content of `application-core.properties` consists of credentials needed to access an API:

```
url: xyc.com
username: usr
password: pw
```

This API call and the logic associated with it occurs in `application-core` but I call the relevant methods from `application-app`. How do I "import" and run my `application-app` with both the `dev` profile as well as the `core` profile? I tried adding `spring.profiles.include:` in my `application-dev.yml` but I got this exception:

```
org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException: Property 'spring.profiles.include' imported from location 'class path resource [application-dev.yml]' is invalid in a profile specific resource [origin: class path resource [application-dev.yml] - 17:14]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.lambda$throwOrWarn$1(InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.throwOrWarn(InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.checkForInvalidProperties(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:354)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.applyToEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:323)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:236)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at at.application.main(application.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

`application-dev.yml` contains properties for the data source, logging and server.

Comment: does this answer your question?  Basically you will need to call the two or more profiles in your run arguments:  mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=core,dev

Comment: @SusanMustafa thank you for your comment, this helped me. I tried to simply add a comma and the core profile to my run configuration profile settings in STS and it worked. Thanks again